# Is a tracheal consonant possible?

Tags: conlang, frontness-backness

I was thinking about whether a tracheal consonant is possible or not. This is a sound through the windpipe. If this type of sound is indeed possible, can we make this sound easily?

Someone else came up with this idea:http://archives.conlang.info/cae/penfhen/jhirfhueltuen.html

Comment: If kicked correctly into the bowels, a person can well produce even a _rectal_ sound. This kind of sound can be produced even intentionally. There are also [arm-pit sounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDMB074Klbs) and various sounds one can produce with the palms: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0CuLotR11o

Comment: Funny. But what about the trachea?

Comment: In case of trachea, the aim of one's heel is to be not the bowels, but _Plexus coeliacus_, the solar plexus, that's all.

Comment: As far as I know, we have no muscle or mechanism to close or narrow the trachea, apart from physically pressing on it (or kicking it, as Yellow Sky suggests); when we ‘close’ the trachea, we do so with the epiglottis, which is an already existing point of articulation that is used in languages. As such, I don’t see how a tracheal consonant would be possible. Even if we could control the trachea like that, it’s below the vocal cords, so I doubt it would be distinguishable from glottal consonants.

Comment: @Janus that should be an answer, not a comment, shouldn't it?

Comment: @OmarL It’s too speculative for an answer, I’d say. I’m not an anatomist, and I don’t actually know if what I supposed is actually actually – it’s just my immediate assumptions. If someone has more certain knowledge, I have no objection to them turning it into an answer.